# Creating swift class subclass of NSObject gives compiler error

Tags: swift, ios8, subclassing

I have a swift class which is sub class of NSObject type and this class has only properties not even single method (function). i'm new learner of swift so please help with simple description here is my code.

```
class DBObject_Swift : NSObject
{

    //Objects for Category table.
        var CId : Int!
        var strCType : NSString!

    //Objects for Event table.
        var EId : Int!
        var ECId : Int!
        var strETitle : NSString!
        var strEDateTime : NSString!
        var strOccurrence : NSString!

    //Objects for ToDoEvent table.
        var TDId : Int!
        var TDEId : Int!
        var TDCId : Int!
        var strTask : NSString!
        var strDate : NSString!
        var strTDOccurrence : NSString!
        var isCompleted : Int!
}
```

But it gives compiler error.  and right-now i'm doing migration and both class like objective c and swift class in same project  here is my project class structure.

[image] 
my project structure is same for every class in project .h & .m for objective c and .swift for swift

and error screen is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

header i missing.
So you can't you the DBObject.h header.

How to create a Bridging-Header [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: i use bredging header and this header is for when you want to use objective c class object in swift class only that time you have to import so that's why i'm not import DBObject.h header in bridging

Comment: and i already done like you told but no effect. just see my project structure there is 2 separate classes 1st for objective c and 2nd is for swift so no need to import in bridging header

Comment: Look at your DBObject  class in your swift cass i see nothing the can create an exception.

Comment: Here is new error error: could not import Objective-C header 'Event Organizer-Bridging-Header.h'

Comment: sorry i cant show you and now my error solve so thanks for hint the problem is another but your answer is used as a hint

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Xcode Beta 4. At the very least try using the latest release version Xcode 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

To use Swift code in your Objective-C code, you have to include in your .m or .h file the following line (substitute `'ProductModuleName'` with the name of your target):

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

Your Swift class needs to be a descendant of `NSObject`, or you have to prefix your Swift class with `@objc`.

There is a really great explanation about how this works in the iBook *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*.